# Where to buy a condensed set of Shas Talmud Bavli books

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, jewish-books

I am looking for all of shas in 1 condensed set (1-6 books) without any commentaries in the back (just the Gemarah, Rashi, Tos.).

Does anybody know where I can buy this and if they ship to the United States?

Comment: I have a set I'm staring at right now... [Oz Vehadar...](http://www.oz-vehadar.com/en/department/15/oz-vehadar-shas-editions)

Comment: It's pretty no-frills, Vilna shas G/R/T, but it also includes all of seder zeraim, apparently. No real additional commentary in the back (they have hashmatot milikutei rashi, but that's basically it).

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky: Thanks for the link. Are you referring to the 6 book set? Does it have Taharot too? It's interesting that the 5 set is more expensive than the 6. Is it because of the extra binding? They seem good, but I'd prefer a cheaper set and less books if possible.

Comment: Why less books? they end up being the same size in aggregate...

Comment: @Isaac: I figured no seder zraim and hashmatot adds up. So I'd prefer an older set. But this set seems fine. It's just that I'd rather pay $50-75 than $120-150.

Comment: see my answer - talman shas can be had for around $80

Comment: As far as I can tell, both the Oz Vehadar 5 volume and the Talman 20 volume (and presumably the 6 volume) contain all of shas, both mishna and talmud bavli. That includes the remaining masechtot in seder Zeraim and Taharos. From the Eichler's website, it looks like the Talman 6 volume may ***not*** have the remainder of Taharos based on the visible label on the sixth volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oz vehadar makes no-frills 5 and 6 volume sets. My 5 volume set is about 8 inches tall, and each volume is about 2 inches wide.

There are a [number](http://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/oz-vehadar-shas-set-5-volumes-hardcover-997396.html) of [places](http://www.eichlers.com/seforim/shas/shas-oz-vehader-ubelectecha-6-vol.html) to [get](http://www.seforimcenter.com/product.asp?numPageStartPosition=1&P_ID=8542&strPageHistory=&strKeywords=&strSearchCriteria=&PT_ID=360) them in the US. They run around $110-130, though you can probably find them cheaper during a sale. The all [paperback 20 volume set](http://seforimsets.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=2&product_id=4283) is $80. You can even purchase them directly from Oz Vehadar in Israel if you're interested, but they aren't any cheaper and you'll spend a fortune on shipping.

Cheapest Oz Vehadar 6 volume set I've found: [$105](http://seforimsets.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=2&product_id=591)

[Talman shas](http://www.eichlers.com/seforim/shas/shas-talman-6-vol-small-ws-tlmn-qtn-6-krkim.html) is [also](http://seforimsets.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=2&product_id=107) a good one - I use my mini set as my "every day" reference. They're cheaper than Oz Vehadar, and typically printed an a thinner and lighter stock of paper. People tend to feel that the printing on the Oz Vehadar is better and "cleaner," but I'm not sure there is much of a difference in the newest printings. They tend to run in the $80's before shipping.

Comment: For the 5/6 volume Oz Vehadar sets, how does each book compare to the weight of a 1000 page physiology textbook? The large Oz Vehadar shas is really heavy.